# Is the mean of orthonormal matrices also orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I have a $T \times 3$ matrix $X$ where the columns are orthonormal. Then I have $N$ orthonormal rotation matrices $Q_i$ where $i = 1, ..., N$. All matrices $Q_i$ are orthonormal and of size $3 \times 3$. $Q$ is the (element-by-element) mean of all matrices $Q_i$.

Is the product $XQ$ also orthonormal?

Comment: What have you tried? What about the case of the mean of just two matrices? How can you tell if a matrix is orthonormal?

Comment: Your title does not match with your writeup (as currently stated, without making further assumptions about what can be deduced). You're not trying to show that $Q$ is orthonormal, but that $XQ$ is orthonormal.

Comment: If $Q_j=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{2\pi j}N&-\sin\frac{2\pi j}N & 0\\ \sin\frac{2\pi j}N &\cos\frac{2\pi j}N&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ then $\frac1N\sum_{j=1}^N Q_j=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @FedePoncio If I only have one $Q$, I know that $(XQ)'(XQ)=I$ since $Q'Q=I$ and $X' X=I$ by orthonormality. However, I have no idea what properties remain when taking the mean of matrices. I think the problem is the same when $N=2$

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for the comment. The title is probably oversimplified. However, I think that orthonormality prevails if $Q$ is orthonormal, so I essentially need to figure out whether the mean of orthonormal matrices is orthonormal, if I am not mistaken